# Reset Password Parse Server Manually,Server Side

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform, server

I want to set password of a user with email x@x.com to be "an". But the code doesn't  work.
Here is my cloud code:

```
  Parse.Cloud.define('testSetPasswordForUser', function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
 query.equalTo("email", "x@x.com");

  query.first({
  success: function(results) {
    results.setPassword("an");
    results.save();
  },
  error: function(error) {

  }
});



});
```

and here is my android code:

```
     Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                   ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("testSetPasswordForUser", parameters, new FunctionCallback<Map<String, Object>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(Map<String, Object> mapObject, ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
//OK
                                }
                                else {
//WRONG
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you're gonna throw an error if there isn't a matching e-mail, since `results` will be undefined. So wrap the handler in an `if( results )` block.

Second, you have to use the master key to change a password. Otherwise, anybody could change anybody else's password.

`results.save(null, {useMasterKey:true});`

The null is an optional dictionary you could be updating values in. I.e.
`results.save({key1:value1, key2:value2}, {useMasterKey:true});`